# How to write all socket.io server console text into txt file?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

My socket server shuts down sometimes and I can't check why because there is no txt log where i could check last error messages, maybe there is way to write it in txt file after shutting down?

Comment: Can you share the minimal code for the web server?

Comment: server have 667 lines and length: 19674 :/ so little peace of code couldn't help I think

Comment: Hmm. That's going to make things difficult...

Comment: socket.io shows error only couple milliseconds and shuts down thats annoying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke your program in the following way: `node myserver.js 2> error_log.txt`

When the program closes the error_log txt will have all messages, including the error message that made the program crash written in it.

To also get all console.log messages you can do `node myserver.js > error_log.txt > 2>&1`

(I used this command in the bash console on windows)

Comment: 2> Redirects the error message to the output (stderr). With just > the stdout is outputted.

Comment: What console are you using? It should work on linux or bash on windows.

Comment: when i try second way server shuts down

Comment: i use windows .bat file

Comment: I've tried it with a .bat and it should work. You can do this `.\myserver.bat 2> error_log.txt`